# C# How to check if number is larger?

Tags: c#

I'm working on a program for my class at school and I'm setting up AutoUpdates. Is there any way to make "else if (webClient.DownloadString("mylink").Contains("0.3.9"))" check the contains of the link to see if it is over or greater than 0.3.9??

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();  
        if (File.Exists(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "\\DesktopReborn\\updates\\Update-0.4.0.xml")) { }

        else if (webClient.DownloadString("mylink").Contains("0.3.9"))
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("An Update is Avaliable, Would you like to download it?", "DesktopReborn Updater", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                webClient.DownloadFile("myupdate", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "\\DesktopReborn\\DesktopReborn.exe");

                if (File.Exists(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "\\DesktopReborn\\updates\\Update-0.3.9.xml"))
                {
                    File.Copy(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "\\DesktopReborn\\updates\\Update-0.3.9.xml", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "\\DesktopReborn\\updates\\Update-0.4.0.xml", true);
                    File.Delete(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "\\DesktopReborn\\updates\\Update-0.3.9.xml");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @TheGeneral The "mylink" is https://pastebin.com/BajyfKbD and the "myupdate" is a .exe file I have stored on a website.

Comment: Ok so it just comes with 3 numbers separated by 2 full stops

Comment: @TheGeneral um i don't know what you mean by that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET Framework comes with `System.Version` class that allows you to compare between version number.

```
var newVersion = new Version("0.3.9");
var oldVersion = new Version("0.3.8");

if(oldVersion < newVersion)
{
   //do something..
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If your format is `xx.xx.xx` you could just parse it into a `Version` Class

```
private static Version _someAribtaryVersion = new Version("2.3.5")

...

var someFunkyNumber = webClient.DownloadString("mylink");

var version = new Version(someFunkyNumber);

if(version > _someAribtaryVersion)
   // Bingo!
```

**Additional Resources**

[Version Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version?view=netstandard-1.6)

> Represents the version number of an assembly, operating system, or the
>   common language runtime.

Also the advantage is it already comes with built in operators

[Version.GreaterThan(Version, Version) Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version.op_greaterthan?view=netstandard-1.6)

> Determines whether the first specified Version object is greater than
>   the second specified Version object.

Which means you can compare 2 *Versions* with `>`, `=`, `<`, `>=`, `<=`

also some useful parsing methods

[Version.Parse Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version.parse?view=netstandard-1.6)

> Converts the string representation of a version number to an
>   equivalent Version object.

Comment: Wow, you learn something new every day - I'd never seen this class before (I've been working in .NET stuff since a month or two before the first beta back in 2000).  Thanks!

Comment: @Flydog57: Always use the version class! It prevents making all kinds of crazy bugs. People try to do things like compare versions as strings, forgetting that "3.14" should be larger, not smaller, than "3.2". People do things like write `if(x.Major >= y.Major && x.Minor >= y.Minor)` forgetting that 3.2 is greater than 2.3.  It is surprisingly easy to make mistakes, so encapsulate the logic in a class that gets it right once.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `Version` class to parse and compare strings like that, for example:

```
string thisVersion = "0.3.9";
string newVersion = "0.4.0";

if (Version.Parse(newVersion) > Version.Parse(thisVersion))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{newVersion} is greater than {thisVersion}");
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: I like your parse version, no fuss and neat, also need to use up my upvotes for the day

Comment: Thank you! I suppose I should have mentioned something about `TryParse` instead, but after I posted it I saw you already had a nice, detailed answer so I bow to you... :)